# Font Awesome Pro 6.0 Duotone icons layer position problem

Tags: css, font-awesome

I have the font awesome 6.0 Pro version. But the problem is, Duotone icon layer position is not setting properly. Look at my approach and screenshot.

```
    <style type="text/css">
.fa-duotone{
font-size:30px;
text-align:center;}
</style>

<i class="fa-duotone fa-crow" style="--fa-secondary-opacity: 1.0; --fa-primary-color: dodgerblue; --fa-secondary-color: gold;"></i>
<i class="fa-duotone fa-campfire" style="--fa-secondary-opacity: 1.0; --fa-primary-color: sienna; --fa-secondary-color: red;"></i>
```

Look at the Screenshot:
[Font Awesome Duotone Icon Layer Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uvprg.jpg)

How Can I Fix It......?

Comment: I believe this is the same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74825137/font-awesome-upgrade-version-5-to-version-6-duotone-icons-not-displayed-properl/75531612#75531612 - good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case if layer disposition is happening on upload of custom duotone icons in FontAwesome Kit, to save someone hustle I went trough- 'custom icon upload feature does not support the duotone style just yet' (as of moment writing this) so when you upload SVG it transfers layers into single layer and you see dispositioned layers. Needless to say you lose opacity on layers as well.