# Font Awesome Upgrade Version 5 to Version 6 -Duotone Icons not displayed properly

Tags: font-awesome

I upgraded a project from Font Awesome 5 to Font Awesome 6. Everything is working fine, yet every Icon with an duotone attribute is displayed incorrectly. I noticed that the duotone.less file is much smaller for Version6 than for Version5 and that no ::after elements are displayed. I wonder if someone else had the same or similar issue.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're compiling Font Awesome yourself via SCSS - if so there's an additional `@import` required as outlined in the [Font Awesome docs](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/use-with/scss) that wasn't needed in version 5

Font Awesome 6 requires an additional file `_duotone-icons.scss`:

```
// our project needs Duotone - which requires both of the following files
@import "./fontawesome/scss/duotone.scss";
@import "./fontawesome/scss/_duotone-icons.scss";
```